# fetch apps from google play store and show them in list

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

How I can fetch a free application list from google play store and show them in a list view? Is it possible or not?
I searched a lot from google but found nothing related to this.If anybody knows this answer please tell.

I will be very thankful.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) and this GitHub [project](https://github.com/MarcelloLins/GooglePlayAppsCrawler).

Comment: i want to fetch all apps at a time (free apps)